# Magento 2 - No theme is loading

Tags: magento2, theme

After creating and deploying a new module following [this](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-1-setup/) article, no theme loaded anymore.
I've tried to change the theme to luma or my custom theme, but there is no effect.

What can I do to enable displaying any theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself. I compared the \pub\static folder of two magento installations and saw that the htaccess file is missing. After pasting and deploying the static content the themes are displayed correctly.